# Embedding custom posts with REST API

Tags: embed, rest-api

I am trying to find a way to embed basing custom post infomation, such as post title and few custom metas on other website.

The easiest seems to be doing it in iFrame, but there are many "no's", you can't style it as much as you want etc. So after update to 4.7 and avaiability of REST API I though it would be great to use that, and retrievve needed values with API call. But when I try to use `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/11` where `11` is custom post type called `st_activity`, I'm getting post content and all the information but my custom meta is missing.

I've registered custom post type with API support, following

> http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/

adding

```
'show_in_rest'       => true,
'rest_base'          => 'activity-api',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
```

and adjusted meta:

```
function slug_register_rate_review() {
            register_rest_field( 'st_activity',
                'rate_review',
            array(
                'get_callback' => 'slug_get_st_activity',
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema' => null,
            )
        );
    }

    function slug_get_st_activity($post, $field_name, $request) {
        return get_post_meta($post['id'], 'rate_review' );
    }
```

Well, obviously I'm doing something wrong but have no idea what exactly.

And ddespite that, is it possible and how to get only title, link, and custom meta without all the other values? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint is wrong, `/wp/v2/posts` is just for objects with `post_type='post'`. If your custom post type is registered with 'activity-api' the endpoint would be `/wp/v2/activity-api/11`.

That's because it's the slug you registered in `'rest_base' => 'activity-api'` argument to your post type. Without a custom `rest_base` argument, the endpoint would be at `/wp/v2/st_activity`